# Javascript - Dynamic object keys (second key)

Tags: javascript

I can create a dynamic object as follows:

```
var year=2103;
var month=9;

var selected={};
selected[year][month]=true;
```

But the following gives an undefined object error I presume because the first key has not been created and Javascript is not automatically doing that.

```
selected[year]=true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But the following gives an undefined object error I presume because the first key has not been created and Javascript is not automatically doing that.

Yes, you have to create it:

```
var year = 2103;
var month = 9;
var selected = {};
selected[year] = {};
selected[year][month] = true;
```

If you're unsure if the object already exists, and do not want to overwrite it:

```
selected[year] = selected[year] || {};
```

As a shortcut to populate the object if missing & assign the month key in one step:

```
(selected[year]||(selected[year]={}))[month] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a step: selected[year]=[];

```
var year=2103;
var month=9;

var selected=[];

selected[year]=[];

selected[year][month]=true;
```